# Angular 2 parent child comunication

Tags: typescript, angular, components, parent

I have 2 component: RegistrationComponent and RegistryComponent.

RegistrationComponent:

```
@Component({
selector: 'registration_page',
template: 
'<div>
    <registry_form [model]="parentModel"></registry_form>
    <label>{{parentModel}}</label>
</div>,
styleUrls: [...],
directives: [...],
providers: []
})
export class RegistrationComponent 
{
   parentModel : string;

   constructor()
   {
      this.parentModel = "parent"
   }
}
```

RegistryComponent:

```
@Component({
selector: 'registry_form',
template: 
'
  <label for="name">name {{model}}</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model" required >
',
styleUrls: [...],
directives: [...]
})

export class RegistryFormComponent 
{
   @Input() model;
}
```

When I write some text in input in RegistryComponent I can see changes but not in RegistrationComponent witch is the parent component. What I'm missing?

Comment: https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
<registry_form [model]="parentModel"></registry_form>
```

The `[]` part means that this will be an "input" binding type. You can make the thing work in 2 ways:

1) Change the binding to be

```
<registry_form [(model)]="parentModel"></registry_form>
                ^     ^
```

e.g. "banana in the box". But this is just a "syntactical sugar", so you would also need to implement an `Output() modelChange` property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'registry_form',
  template: `
    <label for="name">name {{model}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange)="modelChange.next($event)" required >
  `,
})
export class RegistryFormComponent {
   @Input() model: any;
   @Output() modelChange = new EventEmitter();
}
```

2) Make the `parentModel` an object with a `name` property, and pass this whole object:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'registry_form',
  template: `
    <label for="name">name {{model.name}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="model.name" required >
  `,
})
export class RegistryFormComponent {
   @Input() model: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'registration_page',
  template: `
  <div>
      <registry_form [model]="parentModel"></registry_form>
      <label>{{parentModel.name}}</label>
  </div>`,
  directives: [RegistryFormComponent],
})
export class RegistrationComponent {
   parentModel : any;

   constructor() {
      this.parentModel ={name:"parent"};
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you man! You save me...I managed this to work eliminating at all registry component and put his HTML into registration page...but this is the solution I was looking for!

Comment: Which option is the best one ? @Dethariel

Answer (score 0):

Because It's a one way binding. Child has its own scope. Whenever changes you do in child will stay in child.

If child need to update the changes and notify parent, need to use event.